# select sliced columns with fixed ones

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, slice

I have the following df:

```
KSCHL01     VTEXT01         KWERT01     KSCHL02     VTEXT02                 KWERT02     KSCHL03     VTEXT03         KWERT03     id
ZBTB        Tarif de base   4455.00     ZBFA        Brut facturé            4455.00     ZBN Brut    Négocié         3645.00     1
ZBT         Brut Tarif.     222.75      ZFIF        Remises fin d'ordre     0.00        ZMAJ        Majorations     0.00        2
```

I may have more than 13 columns.
I want to transform every 3 columns slice to a line, to have this EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
id  KSCHL   VTEXT                   KWERT
1   ZBTB    Tarif de base           4455.00
1   ZBFA    Brut facturé            4455.00
1   ZBN     Brut Négocié            3645.00
2   ZBT     Brut Tarif.             222.75
2   ZFIF    Remises fin d'ordre     0.00
2   ZMAJ    Majorations             0.00
```

I did this:

```
for( i <- 0 to df.columns.length-4 by 3){
  var temp=df.select(df.columns.slice(i, i+3).map(col(_)): _*)
  val columns = temp.columns
  val regex = """[0-9]"""
  val replacingColumns = columns.map(regex.r.replaceAllIn(_, "")) # delete all digits in column names
  val resultDF = replacingColumns.zip(columns).foldLeft(temp){(tempdf, name) => tempdf.withColumnRenamed(name._2, name._1)}
  res=res.union(resultDF) # Append df to final DF
}
```

which gives me this:

```
KSCHL   VTEXT                   KWERT
ZBTB    Tarif de base           4455.00
ZBFA    Brut facturé            4455.00
ZBN     Brut Négocié            3645.00
ZBT     Brut Tarif.             222.75
ZFIF    Remises fin d'ordre     0.00
ZMAJ    Majorations             0.00
```

How can I add the id column to every slice in order to have it as a column like in the desired output? I tried:

```
temp = temp.withColumn("id", df.id)
```

but I had this error:

```
error: value id in class Dataset cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Thank you.

Comment: haha, can you add excepted output ?

Comment: The second block is my expected output, sorry it was not very clear

Comment: what if your dataframe is not contains equal number of columns say `KSCHL01`, `KSCHL02` columns &  `KSCHL03` is missed ?

Comment: It cant happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can rewrite the code, Adjust the range dynamically as the numbers of columns

```
val range = (1 to 3).map(r => if (r < 10) s"0$r" else s"$r")

val structQuery = $"id" +: range.map(n =>
  struct($"KSCHL$n".as("KSCHL"), $"VTEXT$n".as("VTEXT"), $"KWERT$n".as("KWERT")).as(s"struct$n")
)

df.select(structQuery: _*)
  .withColumn("new", explode(array(range.map(r => col(s"struct$r")): _*)))
  .select("id", "new.*")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-------------------+------+
|id |KSCHL|VTEXT              |KWERT |
+---+-----+-------------------+------+
|1  |ZBTB |Tarif de base      |4455.0|
|1  |ZBFA |Brut facturé       |4455.0|
|1  |ZBN  |Brut    Négocié    |3645.0|
|2  |ZBT  |Brut Tarif.        |222.75|
|2  |ZFIF |Remises fin d'ordre|0.0   |
|2  |ZMAJ |Majorations        |0.0   |
+---+-----+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: This works only for range 1 to 9 max. If more: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`KSCHL010`' given input columns.
the 10th triplets is actually KSCHL10 not KSCHL010. 
Any fix please ?

Comment: @Haha Updated: Take a look it would be simple to fix

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+------------+-------+---+--------------+
|KSCHL01|VTEXT01      |KWERT01|KSCHL02|VTEXT02            |KWERT02|KSCHL03|VTEXT03     |KWERT03|id |KSCHL04       |
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+------------+-------+---+--------------+
|ZBTB   |Tarif de base|4455.00|ZBFA   |Brut facturé       |4455.00|ZBN    |Brut Négocié|3645.00|1  |sample KSCHL03|
|ZBT    |Brut Tarif.  |222.75 |ZFIF   |Remises fin d'ordre|0.00   |ZMAJ   |Majorations |0.00   |2  |sample KSCHL03|
+-------+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+------------+-------+---+--------------+
```

```
scala> val singleColumns = df.columns.filter(c => c.filter(_.isDigit).length == 0).map(col)
singleColumns: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(id)
```

```
scala> val multipleColumns = df.columns.filter(c => c.filter(_.isDigit).length != 0).map(c => (c.filterNot(_.isDigit),c,c.filter(_.isDigit)))
multipleColumns: Array[(String, String, String)] = Array((KSCHL,KSCHL01,01), (VTEXT,VTEXT01,01), (KWERT,KWERT01,01), (KSCHL,KSCHL02,02), (VTEXT,VTEXT02,02), (KWERT,KWERT02,02), (KSCHL,KSCHL03,03), (VTEXT,VTEXT03,03), (KWERT,KWERT03,03), (KSCHL,KSCHL04,04))
```

```
scala> val distinctColumns = multipleColumns.map(_._1).distinct
distinctColumns: Array[String] = Array(KSCHL, VTEXT, KWERT)
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val colExpr = array(
             multipleColumns
             .groupBy(_._3)
             .map(k => struct(
                k._2.map(c => col(c._2).as(c._1)) ++
                distinctColumns.filter(c => k._2.filter(_._1 == c).length == 0).map(c => lit("").as(c)) ++
                singleColumns:_*
            ).as("data"))
            .toSeq:_*
        ).as("array_data")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

colExpr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = array(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), KSCHL03 AS `KSCHL`, NamePlaceholder(), VTEXT03 AS `VTEXT`, NamePlaceholder(), KWERT03 AS `KWERT`, NamePlaceholder(), id) AS `data`, named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), KSCHL02 AS `KSCHL`, NamePlaceholder(), VTEXT02 AS `VTEXT`, NamePlaceholder(), KWERT02 AS `KWERT`, NamePlaceholder(), id) AS `data`, named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), KSCHL01 AS `KSCHL`, NamePlaceholder(), VTEXT01 AS `VTEXT`, NamePlaceholder(), KWERT01 AS `KWERT`, NamePlaceholder(), id) AS `data`, named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), KSCHL04 AS `KSCHL`, VTEXT,  AS `VTEXT`, KWERT,  AS `KWERT`, NamePlaceholder(), id) AS `data`) AS `array_data`
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val finalDF = df
.select(colExpr)
.withColumn("array_data",explode_outer($"array_data"))
.select("array_data.*")


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

```
finalDF.show(false)
+--------------+-------------------+-------+---+
|KSCHL         |VTEXT              |KWERT  |id |
+--------------+-------------------+-------+---+
|ZBN           |Brut Négocié       |3645.00|1  |
|ZBFA          |Brut facturé       |4455.00|1  |
|ZBTB          |Tarif de base      |4455.00|1  |
|sample KSCHL03|                   |       |1  |
|ZMAJ          |Majorations        |0.00   |2  |
|ZFIF          |Remises fin d'ordre|0.00   |2  |
|ZBT           |Brut Tarif.        |222.75 |2  |
|sample KSCHL03|                   |       |2  |
+--------------+-------------------+-------+---+
```

Comment: what if I have more columns ? Here I took an example with 3 triplets (_01, _02 and 03). 
What If I have 30 triplets ? That is why I used 
for( i <- 0 to df.columns.length-4 by 3){
  var temp=df.select(df.columns.slice(i, i+3).map(col(_)): _*)